# Changing Project Type from Object Detection to Instance Segmentation in Roboflow

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, image-segmentation, roboflow

I have been working on a computer vision project using Roboflow, where I initially created a project for object detection. However, as the project progressed, I realized that instance segmentation would better suit my needs. Now, I am looking for guidance on how to change the project type from object detection to instance segmentation in Roboflow.

Important Point: My labelled data is suitable for instance segmentation. I have carefully annotated the images with individual instance masks for the objects of interest, which makes it compatible with instance segmentation tasks.

Specifically, I want to know if there is a direct way to modify the project type within the Roboflow platform or if there are alternative methods to achieve this transition effectively. I have invested time in labeling my data for object detection, and I would like to leverage that work to avoid starting from scratch with instance segmentation.

If anyone has encountered a similar situation or is familiar with Roboflow's capabilities, your insights would be greatly appreciated. Any step-by-step instructions or tips on how to handle this project type transition would be valuable.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The easiest way is to download as COCO format & re-upload to a new instance-segmentation project.

Comment: After exporting the dataset, while training the yolo v8 segment model, I have encountered the following error:
RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 24 but got size 0 for tensor number 1 in the list.
TypeError: ERROR ❌ segment dataset incorrectly formatted or not a segment dataset.
This error can occur when incorrectly training a 'segment' model on a 'detect' dataset, i.e. 'yolo train model=yolov8n-seg.pt data=coco128.yaml'.
Verify your dataset is a correctly formatted 'segment' dataset using 'data=coco128-seg.yaml' as an example.

Comment: Is there any other workaround for this problem?

Comment: Maybe try exporting as COCO-Segmentation which will turn any boxes into 4-point polygons.